# Basis for the space of all polynomials of degree over $\mathbb R$ less than or equal to $n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening. How I can show that the set $B=\left\{1,(x-a),\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!},...,\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}\right\}$, $a\in \mathbb{R}$ forms a basis for the space that I mentioned?

My Work:

I know that this is related to Taylor's formula, for example, have already proved that $B$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}$, because $B$ consists of polynomials of different degree and that guarantees me the linear independency, my biggest question is to see that $B$ is a system of generators to $\mathbb{R_n}[x]$.

If you could help me with this problem would be great, or even give me another idea to test the linear independence, I would be very grateful. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to prove that directly. What is the dimension of $B$?

Comment: (1) If you're going by the definition, you need to show that $B$ spans $\mathbb R_n[x]$. So write a polynomial as a linear combination of the elements of $B$. (Use Taylor's formula here.) (2) If $n$ is the dimension of $V$, and $S$ is a set of $n$ linearly independent elements of $V$, then $S$ also spans $V$.

Comment: You can easily prove a more general result: if in your set there is one polynomial of each degree, then the set is a basis. Has nothing to do with Taylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this result directly by showing that there exists a unique $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ satisfying $f(a)=t_0$, $f'(a)=t_1$, $\ldots$, $f^{(n)}(a)=t_n$ for any fixed $t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Existence:** $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\,t_i\,\frac{(x-a)^i}{i!}$ would do.

**Uniqueness:** If $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ is another such polynomial, then show that $f(x)-g(x)=P(x)\,(x-a)^{n+1}$ for some $P(x)\in\mathbb{R[x]}$ (whence $P(x)=0$).

Hence, your set $B$ does span $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$.  For linear independence of $B$, you can again use the uniqueness lemma above to show that $f(x)=0$ is the only element of $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$ whose $i$-th derivative at $a$ vanishes for all $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n$.

***P.S.:***  $\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced by any field of characteristic $0$.